# Grunt watch keeps watching infinite

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Hi I'm using Grunt to compile my less code to CSS. To see if I have made changes to my .less file I use:

```
grunt watch
```

After doing that, I was editing my .less file. But nothing happens in cmd I still see that he is watching to my .less file. Here is a screenshot of it:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b25B3.png

Here is the code that I use:

gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "css/styles.css": "css/styles.less" // destination file and source file
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['less/styles.less'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Coming_soon_code",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "van een tut",
  "main": "gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1"
  }
}
```

Also here is a screenshot of my folder structure in case if you need it:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLCmd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be "watching" the `'less/styles.less'` file... but that is not the correct directory according to your screenshot or `less` task config, it's in the `css` directory. Try this maybe:

```
watch: {
  styles: {
    files: ['css/styles.less'], // <-- changed the directory here...
    tasks: ['less'],
    options: {
      nospawn: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer works! Also do you know how to not minify me .css file? I have already tried: css: ['concat'] in my gruntfile.js, but that doesn't works. I don't want to minify my .css file because sometimes I'm curious how my .css looks like after it was compiled from the .less file.

Comment: Looks like you want to set the [`compress` option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#compress) to `false`, but that's the default (so it should not be minifying by default)...